# Problems with old system title tag using Kohana

Tags: php, kohana

This last week i have been trying to solve some problems in an old website using Kohana.
My problem is: I am trying to make changes in  tag, but when i make changes on it, title is appearing different that it should, for example, if i say, title = myNewTitle... Title is appearing MyNewTitleMyOldTitle. So it s not appearing just the new one dynamic title, its appearing the old one, and the new, both together, can someone help me please?

```
$this->template->meta['title'] = 'Administrativo - Comentários - ' . $this->template->site;
```

This is the code what define my title.

Answer (score 0):

This is not from the kohana core:

```php
$this->template->meta['title']
```

The [$template](https://koseven.dev/documentation/api/Controller_Template#property-template) variable points to some `application/views/` file, also the *OldTitle* can be set permanently.

This can also be overridden by the [Controller::after()](https://koseven.dev/documentation/api/Controller_Template#after) method.

Without a deeper analysis of the code, I cannot give you any more detailed information. In fact, you can search yourself: `die($this->template->meta['title'] )` in controller, `die($meta['title'] )` in views.